# Regexp - Capture Multiples of a Submatch

Tags: regex, go

I'm looking to capture multiple instances of a one or more submatch using regular expressions. I'm just getting the last instance. Is my regexp wrong? Or do I need to instead capture the whole group and split with logic outside the regex?

Minimal example:

```
package main    

import (    
    "fmt"    
    "regexp"    
)    

func main() {    
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`^(\d+)(?:, (\d+))+ - (\w+)`)    
    m := re.FindStringSubmatch("1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - foo")    
    fmt.Printf("m[1:] is %+v\n", m[1:])    
}
```

Prints `m[1:] is [1 5 foo]`

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ELDnhbh727v)

Can I capture `2`, `3`, `4` as separate elements of `m` here?

I know I can get the solution for this example with a larger capture and split:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`^(\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*) - (\w+)`)
    m := re.FindStringSubmatch("1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - foo")
    nums := strings.Split(m[1], `,`)
    for x := 0; x < len(nums); x++ {
        nums[x] = strings.TrimSpace(nums[x])
    }
    fmt.Printf("Nums are %v\n", nums)
    fmt.Printf("Foo is %s\n", m[2])
}
```

Prints

```
Nums are [1 2 3 4 5]
Foo is foo
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/l2VM26nkmki)

Is that the only approach, or is there a regexp solution?

Comment: I don't know Golang (so I hope I'm not wasting your time), but it looks like you may be wanting to do what would in other languages be *matching* the regex `\d+|\w+`. That regex would match each digit and `"foo"` in the string `"1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - foo"`. You appear to be using a single match with three capture groups, so obviously only three substrings are captured.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Appreciate the response. Yes that would work for this example if I use the non-`Submatch` function. My real-life example is a little more complex and I was looking to signal the different portions with different capture groups, but I can review that to see if it will work there too.